# LLDB - How to find functions to add breakpoint?

Tags: macos, lldb

I'm not sure if this question has been asked and answered before, but I will ask it here.

I'm trying to debug a system extension using lldb. I have disassembled the extension in IDA and found the function that I would like to add the breakpoint at --> `FilterDataProvider processEvent`.

However, when I tried to add the breakpoint using `b processEvent`, it threw an error saying:

> Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
>
> WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations

I want to ask if it is possible to list all possible functions of the system extension using lldb? If it is not possible, how would you suggest adding a breakpoint at the *processEvent* function?

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Find the executable extension entry point, cross check with IDA where it is in 
 the executable. Find some system API the system extension is using this may take a couple of tries until you find something called fairly early in the lifetime of the extension. When you get a bp hit use `bt` in lldb. Somewhere in the stacktrace you should have the entry point. Subtract  IDA address of entry point from  Entry point address in runtime. That should be your ASLR vector. Now look up `processEvent` in IDA. Add the ASLR vector to IDA address and set a bp on memory address there.

Comment: If processEvent is a symbol in the symbol table of your extension, then something like `break set -n processEvent -s <NAME_OF_EXTENSION>` should work.  But note, if the extension is loaded after the process starts up, but you set the breakpoint before "running", then the breakpoint will show up as unresolved at first, since lldb has no way to know about this extension until it loads.  But lldb re-tries breakpoints on every subsequent load, so when the extension gets loaded, the breakpoint should resolve.  You'll see a notification in the console to this effect when it happens.

Comment: However, if "FilterDataProvider processEvent" is something IDA Pro made up to make the disassembly clearer, then that won't be something lldb can know about, and you'll have to use addresses as Kamil suggests.